# Virtualized Processor Licencing

Tags: virtualization, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

As I understand it the current state of play with Per-processor or Microsoft licensing (such as SQL) is it is Per "Physical" processor. So if I have a server with two physical slots filled with two physical processors each with four cores I would need two SQL 2008 Licences.

If I was to install VMWare ESX (as an example) on that server then create a machine with four of the cores assigned to the machine presented as 4 Virtual CPUs; would I need one SQL 2008 Per-processor Licence or four?

As a secondary question: Has Microsoft released any official information on this anywhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your understanding is correct.

MS makes this pretty clear in their [special considerations](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/Special-Considerations.aspx) document.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct, you'd only need a single licence as you're not committing to using any cores from a second physical processor - even though the work would likely be split across both. If you gave the VM 5 or more cores in the situation you mention then you would need to buy a second processor licence.